# Cual es el equivalente del debug:router de Symfony en Django?

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Quisiera saber si para Django y/o Django Rest framework existe un comando que me devuelva todas las rutas que hay en mi aplicación.

Busco algo similar a lo devuelto por el comando `debug:router` de Symfony, donde la consola me muestra esto:

```
  especialidad_front                                      GET      ANY      ANY    /especialidad/front                                                         
  especialidad                                            GET      ANY      ANY    /api/especialidad/                                                          
  especialidad_create                                     POST     ANY      ANY    /api/especialidad/                                                          
  especialidad_new                                        GET      ANY      ANY    /api/especialidad/new                                                       
  especialidad_show                                       GET      ANY      ANY    /api/especialidad/{id}                                                      
  especialidad_update                                     PUT      ANY      ANY    /api/especialidad/{id}                                                      
  especialidad_delete                                     DELETE   ANY      ANY    /api/especialidad/{id}
```

Comment: Te sugiero que uses Google para tu investigación o en su lugar que aclares   que problema te estás enfrentando realmente y que como pretendes resolverlo con esa equivalencia. Mira esta guía [ask] y de preferencia agrega un __[mcve]__.

Comment: @toledano Ya he buscado en la Internet y no lo he hallado. Lo que quiero es saber todas las rutas que hay en mi aplicacion. En PHP soy capaz de verlas usando el debug:router pero en Django no se como se hace y lo necesito para mi aplicacion.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, específicando tu necesidad real y pueda ser respondida de forma correcta. Si no tienes interés en corregir la pregunta y prefieres que sea cerrada, te dejo la respuesta que buscas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828187